# yii vendors for all sites

Tags: php, yii

folders structure:

```
htdocs:
--includes
----yii
------framework
--------vendors
----------my_vendor1.php
----------my_vendor2.php
--site1
--site2
```

How to import `my_vendor1.php` and `my_vendor2.php` for `site1`, `site2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that they are inside the `yii/framework` folder as you show, you can easily import anything in the Yii framework directory using the `system` [Path Alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace), like so:

```
Yii::import('system.vendors.*');
```

Assuming both sites using the same Yii installation, you can now call `my_vendor1.php` in either.

You can actually add this to each site's configuration file as well:

```
'import'=>array(
  'application.models.*', // your regular site-specific imports
  'system.vendors.*', // your custom imports
)
```